# IIS Virtual Directory in Azure

Tags: iis, azure, virtual-directory, drives

I've been told that you can create virtual directories in IIS hosted on Azure but I'm struggling to find any info on this as its a relatively new feature. I'd like to point the virtual directory to an Azure Drive (XDrive, NTFS Drive) so that I can reference resources on the drive.

I'm migrating an on premise website onto Azure and need to minimise the amount of rework / redevelopment required. Currently the website has access to shared content folders and I'm trying to mimic a similar set up due to tight time scales.

Does anyone have any knowledge of this or pointers for me as I can't find any information on how to do this?

Any information / pointers you have would be great

Thanks 
Steve

Answer (score 1):

I haven't had a moment to check myself, but get the latest copy of the Windows Azure Platform Training kit. I'm fairly certain that it has a hands on lab that demonstrates the new feature. However, I do not believe that lab includes creating a virtual directory on a azure drive. Even if you can point it there, you may run into some .NET security limitations. http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=413e88f8-5966-4a83-b309-53b7b77edf78&displaylang=en

Another resource to look into might be the stuff Cory Fowler is doing http://blog.syntaxc4.net/ He's been spending some time of late really digging into the internals of the new 1.3 roles. So he might be able to lend you a hand.

Comment: Thanks Brent - I'll look into the things you've provided. All the best

Answer (score 0):

I've been kicking this issue around for sometime now and I can upload a VHD to Azure and I can create a virtual directory in Azure that points to a physical location on my pc  (when running in Dev fabic) and here is the but....

I can't find any examples on where I can do both at the same time, i.e. mount a drive and then map a virtual directory to it.

I've had a look in the 1.3 SDK and looked at various blogs but I can't see any pointers on this - I guess I may have got hold of the wrong end of the stick. If anyone knows how  or if this can be done, that would be great.